# Sending a UDP message to a TCP-connected client in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, udp

I'm building a server and a client in C for an academic project. The objective is to have a server listening for TCP connections and one or more clients connecting to it (each client is handled by different processes in the server). When a client connects to the server, it asks for either a TCP or UDP message, which the server should send and the client receive. (I know this might be an unusual way to do things, but I must follow what was asked) A simplified version of my current progress would be:

client.c:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFER_LEN 512

void error(char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // argument check
    if (argc != 4) {
        printf("Invalid number of arguments.\nSyntax: client <server addr> <port> <protocol>\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    // vars
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    int tcp_fd;
    char buffer[BUFFER_LEN];
    FILE *new_file;

    // get proxy address
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons((short) atoi(argv[2]));

    // create TCP socket
    if ((tcp_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
        error("Unable to create TCP socket");

    // connect to server via TCP
    if (connect(tcp_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
        error("Unable to connect to server");

    // send protocol name to server
    strcpy(buffer, argv[3]);
    write(tcp_fd, buffer, BUFFER_LEN);
    // act according to protocol
    if (!strcmp(buffer, "TCP")) {
        read(tcp_fd, &buffer, BUFFER_LEN);
        puts(buffer);
    } else if (!strcmp(buffer, "UDP")) {
        // ?
        puts(buffer);
    }

    // end
    return 0;
}
```

server.c:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFER_LEN 512
#define SERVER_ADDR "127.0.0.2"

typedef struct {
    char protocol, encryption, filename[BUFFER_LEN / 2];
} download_info;

void error(char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

void process_client(int client_fd, struct sockaddr_in client_addr) {
    char buffer[BUFFER_LEN];
    // receive protocol name from client
    read(client_fd, &buffer, BUFFER_LEN);
    // act according to protocol
    if (!strcmp(buffer, "TCP")) {
        strcpy(buffer, "Hello");
        write(client_fd, buffer, BUFFER_LEN);
    } else if (!strcmp(buffer, "UDP")) {
        // ?
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // argument check
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Invalid number of arguments.\nSyntax: server <port> <max number of clients>\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    // vars
    int tcp_fd, client_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    socklen_t client_addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);

    // get server address struct
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons((short) atoi(argv[1]));
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER_ADDR);

    // create and bind TCP socket, listen for connections
    if ((tcp_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        error("Unable to create TCP socket");
    if (setsockopt(tcp_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){1}, sizeof(int)) < 0)
        error("Unable to set address as reusable");
    if (bind(tcp_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
        error("Unable to bind TCP socket");
    if (listen(tcp_fd, atoi(argv[2])) < 0)
        error("Unable to listen for TCP connections");

    // welcome message
    printf("Server successfully created.\n");

    // server loop
    while (1) {
        // wait for a tcp connection
        client_fd = accept(tcp_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &client_addr_len);
        // handle client in a new process
        if (!fork()) {
            close(tcp_fd);
            process_client(client_fd, client_addr);
            close(client_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(client_fd);
    }
}
```

My question is how I should go about sending the UDP message. I know I need UDP socket in each program, but I'm pretty clueless about how to proceed. I thought about making the client a UDP server and having the server connect to it (?). How should I have the UDP message sent from the server to the client, while being mindful that there can be more than one?

Comment: UDP is a connectionless protocol, so you just have to make sure, that one side binds a socket to a specific port and reads from it, while the other side sends to the ip/port combination. The source port of the sender is irrelevant. So yes, you have to agree on a specific port; either implicitly (a static port number) or explicitly with the UDP request message, with a port number as an argument for example.

Comment: You need to use `recvfrom()` for client and `sendto()` for server. Since UDP is not connection based, you will have to filter data received by client making sure it comes from the same couple IP/port of the server. I'm sorry but I cannot get an answer out of this info because I'm not able to test it right now.